# Excel formula for considering more than 3 columns at the same time

Tags: sql, excel-formula

[image]

Hey guys,As in the table attached,For a policy if there is a combination of both Lost and Issued from the same agency then I don’t want the "Lost" record 
but if the policy has bot lost Issued from different agency then I want all the records. Is there a way to do it with Excel or sql query?

Comment: it not very clear what you say, can you please give us a results screenshot of what you want? and an effort of what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Serial` is in B2 and you want Serial #3 and Serial #3 only identified in the sample provided then, for the sample provided:

```
=IF(AND(C3="Lost",COUNTIFS(C:C,"Lost",D:D,D3,E:E,E3)=COUNTIFS(C:C,"Issued",D:D,D3,E:E,E3)),"#","")
```

in F3 and copied down to suit does so. However it would fail for a situation such as multiple instances of `Lost` and `Issued` for the same `Policy`.